# LC-3 Assembly Need help figuring out why R4 is not getting correct two's complement number

Tags: assembly, lc3

I am making a program that takes userinput of sign (+ or -) and 5 digits. It will then translate the number into 16-bit two's complement. For example, if user enters +7246, R4 will have the number #7246 and/or x1C4E. But, I'm not sure why R4 is not getting the correct number as I am getting #6567/x19A7. Any ideas what could have gone wrong?

```
.ORIG x3000     
;-------------
;Instructions
;-------------
; output intro prompt
    START_PROG
        LD R0, introPromptPtr
        PUTS
; Set up flags, counters, accumulators as needed
    SET_UP
        AND R1, R1, #0
        AND R6, R6, #0 ;if minus then R6 = 1
        LD R3, MAX_COUNT
        AND R4, R4, #0
        
        
;Input check
    CHECK_1
; Get first character, test for '\n', '+', '-', digit/non-digit     
        GETC
        OUT
        LD R2, HEX_0A
        NOT R2, R2
        ADD R2, R2, #1
        ADD R2, R0, R2 ;check if iunput = \n
        BRZ NEWLINE
        
        LD R2, HEX_2B
        NOT R2, R2
        ADD R2, R2, #1
        ADD R2, R0, R2 ;check if iunput = +
        BRZ POSITIVE_1
        
        LD R2, HEX_2D
        NOT R2, R2
        ADD R2, R2, #1
        ADD R2, R0, R2 ;check if iunput = -
        BRZ NEGATIVE_1
        
        LD R2, HEX_30
        NOT R2, R2
        ADD R2, R2, #1
        ADD R2, R0, R2 ;check input num less than hex30 (below hex30)
        BRN ERROR
        
        LD R2, HEX_39
        NOT R2, R2
        ADD R2, R2, #1
        ADD R2, R0, R2 ;check input num more than hex39 (above hex39)
        BRP ERROR
        
        BR NUM_1
        
CHECK_2     
; Get first character, test for '\n', '+', '-', digit/non-digit     
        GETC
        OUT
        
        LD R2, HEX_0A
        NOT R2, R2
        ADD R2, R2, #1
        ADD R2, R0, R2 ;check if iunput = \n
        BRZ NEWLINE
        
        LD R2, HEX_2B
        NOT R2, R2
        ADD R2, R2, #1
        ADD R2, R0, R2 ;check if iunput = +
        BRZ ERROR
        
        LD R2, HEX_2D
        NOT R2, R2
        ADD R2, R2, #1
        ADD R2, R0, R2 ;check if iunput = -
        BRZ ERROR
        
        LD R2, HEX_30
        NOT R2, R2
        ADD R2, R2, #1
        ADD R2, R0, R2 ;check input num less than hex30 (below hex30)
        BRN ERROR
        
        LD R2, HEX_39
        NOT R2, R2
        ADD R2, R2, #1
        ADD R2, R0, R2 ;check input num more than hex39 (above hex39)
        BRP ERROR
        
        BR NUM_1
; is very first character = '\n'? if so, just quit (no message)!
    NEWLINE
        BR QUIT
; is it = '+'? if so, ignore it, go get digits
    POSITIVE_1
        BR CHECK_2
; is it = '-'? if so, set neg flag, go get digits
    NEGATIVE_1
        ADD R6, R6, #1
        BR CHECK_2
; is it < '0'? if so, it is not a digit - o/p error message, start over
    ERROR
        LD R0, errorMessagePtr
        PUTS 
        BR START_PROG
; if none of the above, first character is first numeric digit - convert it to number & store in target register!
    NUM_1
        LD R2, HEX_30
        NOT R2, R2
        ADD R2, R2, #1
        ADD R2, R0, R2 ;converts hex to dec
        ADD R1, R1, R2
        BR REMAIN_NUM
        
    MULTIPLY_TEN
        ADD R1, R1, R2
        ADD R0, R0, #-1
    BRp MULTIPLY_TEN
    
; Now get remaining digits from user in a loop (max 5), testing each to see if it is a digit, and build up number in accumulator
    REMAIN_NUM
        
        GETC
        OUT
        
        LD R2, HEX_0A
        NOT R2, R2
        ADD R2, R2, #1
        ADD R2, R0, R2 ;check if iunput = \n
        BRZ END_LOOP        
        
        BRp MULTIPLY_TEN
        
        LD R2, HEX_30
        NOT R2, R2
        ADD R2, R2, #1
        ADD R2, R0, R2 ;check input num less than hex30 (below hex30)
        BRN ERROR_LOOP
        
        LD R2, HEX_39
        NOT R2, R2
        ADD R2, R2, #1
        ADD R2, R0, R2 ;check input num more than hex39 (above hex39)
        BRP ERROR_LOOP
        
        LD R2, HEX_30
        NOT R2, R2
        ADD R2, R2, #1
        ADD R2, R0, R2 ;converts hex to dec
        BR NUM_LOOP

        ERROR_LOOP
            LD R0, errorMessagePtr
            PUTS
            BR START_PROG
        
        NUM_LOOP
            ADD R1, R1, R2
            AND R2, R2, #0
            ADD R2, R2, R1
        
        ADD R3, R3, #-1
        BRP REMAIN_NUM
        
; remember to end with a newline
    END_LOOP
    ADD R4, R4, R1
    ADD R6, R6, #-1
    BRN END_OF_PROG
    
    NOT_VAL
        NOT R4, R4
        ADD R4, R4, #1
    
    END_OF_PROG
        LD R0, HEX_0A
        OUT
    
    QUIT
HALT

;---------------    
; Program Data
;---------------
MAX_COUNT .fill #4

HEX_0A .fill x0A ;newline
HEX_2B .fill x2B ;plus sign
HEX_2D .fill x2D ;minus sign 
HEX_30 .fill x30 ;dec0 (hex->dec) (lower thresh)
HEX_39 .fill x39 ;dec9 (uppre thresh)

introPromptPtr  .FILL xB000
errorMessagePtr .FILL xB200

.END



;------------
; Remote data
;------------
.ORIG xB000  ; intro prompt
.STRINGZ     "Input a positive or negative decimal number (max 5 digits), followed by ENTER\n"

.END                    
                    
.ORIG xB200  ; error message
.STRINGZ     "ERROR: invalid input\n"

;---------------
; END of PROGRAM
;---------------
.END
```

Comment: What you should do here is sigle step debugging to see where it goes wrong.

Comment: Your `MULTIPLY_TEN` loop has neither `R2` nor `R0` set up properly. Also, it's unclear what you want the `BRp MULTIPLY_TEN` to do and when you expect the following code to be executed.